# Segregation Energy calculation

Tags: surfaces, formation-energy

I am trying to calculate the segregation energy of an element in a slab. The literature I have consulted all says I should calculate the formation energy of the impurity element in the bulk and subtract it from the formation energy at the surface. My question is which bulk are they referring to? The part which has been fixed in the slab model to represent the bulk? Or the isolated bulk material? If it's the former then making a substitution would require a relaxation of the material which is not possible since the bulk part is fixed and hence no ionic movement. How do I go about this?